# KQL to filter out non published hits

Tags: search-results, kql

I want to use a result source to get all published pages of a type in a sitecollection. In a different result source I want also the drafts so I have enabled this possiblity in the libraries. 
However I'm unable to get a filter for Published pages to work.
I have tested all versions I can think of for Page.x ListItem.x but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Moderation Status (ModStat) for this to work.
You need **map crawled property to managed property**.

Crawled property = `ows__ModerationStatus`. "Require Content approval" must be enabled on library (Library Settings > Versioning Settings > **Enable** "Require content approval for submitted items").

Map that crawled property to managed property for ex. `RefinableInt00`.

**Go to** Site Settings > root > Under Site Collection Administration click Search Schema > Crawled Properties; search for ModerationStatus and add to `RefinableInt00` managed property.

**Run full crawl.**
After full crawl you can use `RefinableInt00` in query.

In result source build query something like this:

`RefinableInt00=0` (for approved)

`RefinableInt00=3` (for draft)

**Status**  | **Internal Value**

Approved | 0

Rejected | 1

Pending | 2

Draft | 3

Scheduled | 4